# Investigating Continuity of Partial Derivatives of Multivariable Function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f(x, y) = (x^p + y^q)/(x^2+y^2)$ when $(x, y) \ne 0$  and $0$ otherwise. 
I am attempting to find the values of p, q $\in N$ for which $f(x,y)$ has continuous partial derivatives.

I've computed the partial derivatives for when (x,y) are not 0 and they are

$\partial f /\partial x =\frac{px^{p-1}(x^2+y^2)-2x(x^p+y^q)} {(x^2+y^2)^2}$

$\partial f /\partial y =\frac{qy^{q-1}(x^2+y^2)-2y(x^p+y^q)} {(x^2+y^2)^2}$

Since df/dx and df/dy are polynomials they are continuous on their domain for all natural numbers p and q. It only remains to figure out for which values $p, q \in N$ are df/dx and df/dy continuous at $(0,0)$.

For arbitrary p and q, setting x=0 yields $$\lim_{y\to0} \partial f /\partial x = 0$$
For arbitrary p and q, setting y=0 yields $$\lim_{x\to0} \partial f /\partial y=0$$

Thus, df/dx and df/dy are continuous at (0,0) iff their limits as x and y go to 0 are both 0.
How would you then go about finding the p and q? Intuitively I know that for for the limits of the partial derivatives to go to 0 the expression in the numerator has to go to 0 faster than the expression in the denominator, implying the numerator must be a higher degree polynomial than the denominator. How do I use that intuition to find the smallest p and q for which the condition holds?

Comment: Better to write those as partial derivatives. Use $\partial f /\partial x$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas: first, if $p=1,2$ then $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0).$ Same if $q=1,2.$ So we must have $p,q\ge 3$ just for continuity at $(0,0).$

Let's look at $\partial f /\partial x.$ If $p=3,$ then $\partial f /\partial x(x,0) = 1$ for $x\ne 0.$ That's no good. Suppose $p=4.$ If then $q=3,$ look along the line $(x,x)$ to see there is a problem. So we need $p,q\ge 4.$ Check that $p,q=4$ work in giving the desired continuity of $\partial f /\partial x$ at $(0,0).$ Of course higher values of $p,q$ will then also work.

I'll leave $\partial f /\partial y$ to you.

Comment: Is there anything one can say about $\lim_{X \to 0} \frac{P(X)}{G(X)}$where $X$ is a vector in $R^n$ and P and G are polynomials in X. I want to make a statement to the effect that the limit will be 0 if P is of a higher order than G.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604435/limit-of-ratio-of-2-multivariable-polynomails-proof